# Instance of class is not printing its value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following piece of code:

```
class MyClass {
    var a: String
    var b: String

    init(a: String, b: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}
```

When I try to create the instance of that class (`var c = MyClass(a: "something", b: "else")`) and print the value of `c` to the console all I get is `NAMEOFAPP.MyClass`. I'm a beginner in Swift but I have used classes before and this never happened, it's the first time that I see something like this when creating an instance of a class.

Comment: What do you expect to be printed?

Comment: @vadian I come from a javascript background, so I was expecting it to print something like `{a: "something", b: "else"}`

Comment: @vadian I'm new to swift so I'm guessing this is normal behavior in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adopt `CustomStringConvertible` protocol and override `description`

```
class MyClass : CustomStringConvertible {
    var a: String
    var b: String

    init(a: String, b: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

   var description:String { 
     return "a is : \(a) , b is : \(b)"
   }
}
```

Comment: What does that do?